# name age and upload file not shown in database

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, doctrine-orm

**StudentController.php**

I am uploading image task in symfony but my database not does not show these item but my program working properly and image stored in web\uploads\photos.

This is my StudentController.php any one can help to solve this problem.

```
<?php 
namespace AppBundle\Controller; 

use AppBundle\Entity\Student; 
use AppBundle\Form\FormValidationType; 
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller; 
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route; 

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request; 
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType; 
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType; 
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;  

class StudentController extends Controller {    
   /** 
      * @Route("/student/new") 
   */ 
   public function newAction(Request $request) { 
      $student = new Student(); 
      $form = $this->createFormBuilder($student) 
         ->add('name', TextType::class) 
         ->add('age', TextType::class) 
         ->add('photo', FileType::class, array('label' => 'Photo (png, jpeg)')) 
         ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Submit')) 
         ->getForm(); 

      $form->handleRequest($request); 
      if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) { 
         $file = $student->getPhoto(); 
         $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension(); 
         $file->move($this->getParameter('photos_directory'), $fileName); 
         $student->setPhoto($fileName); 
         return new Response("User photo is successfully uploaded."); 
      } else { 
         return $this->render('student/new.html.twig', array( 
            'form' => $form->createView(), 
         )); 
      } 
   }   
}  


**Student.php**
```

This is my entity class file i maked three field here 1. Name 2. Age 3. photo
but MySql does not show me any update. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkrUK.jpg).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKKgS.jpg), My file uploaded successfully but database not updated

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;



/**
 * Student
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="student")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\StudentRepository")
 */
class Student
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="age", type="integer")
     */
    private $age;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="photo", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $photo;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Student
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set age
     *
     * @param integer $age
     *
     * @return Student
     */
    public function setAge($age)
    {
        $this->age = $age;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get age
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getAge()
    {
        return $this->age;
    }

    /**
     * Set photo
     *
     * @param string $photo
     *
     * @return Student
     */
    public function setPhoto($photo)
    {
        $this->photo = $photo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get photo
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPhoto()
    {
        return $this->photo;
    }
}




**new.html.twig**


{% extends 'base.html.twig' %} 
{% block javascripts %} 
   <script language = "javascript" src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script> 
{% endblock %} 
{% block stylesheets %} 
   <style> 
      #simpleform { 
         width:600px; 
         border:2px solid grey; 
         padding:14px; 
      }  
      #simpleform label { 
         font-size:12px; 
         float:left; 
         width:300px; 
         text-align:right; 
         display:block; 
      } 
      #simpleform span { 
         font-size:11px; 
         color:grey; 
         width:100px; 
         text-align:right; 
         display:block; 
      }  
      #simpleform input { 
         border:1px solid grey; 
         font-family:verdana; 
         font-size:14px; 
         color:grey; 
         height:24px; 
         width:250px; 
         margin: 0 0 20px 10px; 
      }  
      #simpleform button { 
         clear:both; 
         margin-left:250px; 
         background:grey; 
         color:#FFFFFF; 
         border:solid 1px #666666; 
         font-size:16px; 
      } 
   </style> 
{% endblock %} 
{% block body %} 
   <h3>Student form</h3> 
   <div id="simpleform"> 
      {{ form_start(form) }} 
      {{ form_widget(form) }} 
      {{ form_end(form) }} 
   </div>   
{% endblock %}  


parameters: photos_directory: '%kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/photos'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the doctrine entity manager to persist and flush the object in DB.

```
$entityManager->persist($yourEntity);
$entityManager->flush($yourEntity);
```

I recommand you to read symfony documentation about doctrine and the form.

There is your controller action fixed:

```
<?php
class StudentController extends Controller {    
   /** 
      * @Route("/student/new") 
   */ 
   public function newAction(Request $request) { 
      $student = new Student(); 
      $form = $this->createFormBuilder($student) 
         ->add('name', TextType::class) 
         ->add('age', TextType::class) 
         ->add('photo', FileType::class, array('label' => 'Photo (png, jpeg)')) 
         ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Submit')) 
         ->getForm(); 

      $form->handleRequest($request); 
      if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) { 
         $file = $student->getPhoto(); 
         $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension(); 
         $file->move($this->getParameter('photos_directory'), $fileName); 
         $student->setPhoto($fileName); 
         $em = $this->getManager()->getDoctrine();
         $em->persist($student);
         $em->flush();
         return new Response("User photo is successfully uploaded."); 
      } else { 
         return $this->render('student/new.html.twig', array( 
            'form' => $form->createView(), 
         )); 
      } 
   }   
}
```

Comment: If your problem is resolved, please mark your question as answered